# Finding the eyeD3 executable

Tags: python, eyed3

I just installed the abcde CD utility but it's complaining that it can't find eyeD3, the Python ID3 program. This appears to be a well-known and unresolved deficiency in the abcde dependencies, and I'm not a Python programmer, so I'm clueless.

I have the Python 2.7.12 came with Mint 18, and something called python3 (3.5.2). If I try to install eyeD3 with pip (presumably acting against 2.7.12), it says it's already installed (in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eyeD3). I don't know how to force pip to install under python3.

If I do a find / -name eyeD3, the only other thing it turns up is /usr/share/pyshared/eyeD3. But both of those are only directories, and both just contain Python libraries, not executables.

There isn't any other file called eyeD3 anywhere on disk.
Does anyone know what it's supposed to be called, where it's supposed to live, and how I can install it?

P

Comment: The eyeD3 executable is supposed to be at `/usr/local/bin/eyeD3`. To install eyeD3 with python 3, you can use `pip3 install eyeD3`

Comment: Tried that already: doesn't work (see text; pip says it's already installed).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to force pip to install under python3.

`python3 -m pip install eyeD3` will install it for Python3.

Answer (score 1):

Gave up...waste of my time and everyone else's sorry.

What I apparently needed was the eyed3 (lowercase 'd') non-python utility.

Answer (score 0):

It can often be easier to install python packages from your distribution's repository. For example, under Fedora you can do:

`sudo dnf install python-eyed3`

and the `eyeD3` package will be installed on your system.